# Sample PHP code to programmatically check SOAP connection in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento2

I tried the below code though I am not sure whether these are the required set of scripts, but it didn't work and gives

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from  : Start tag expected, '<' not found

```
$wsdlUrl = 'http://localhost/magento20_0407/soap/default?wsdl_list=1';
$apiUser = 'testUser'; 
$apiKey = 'admin123';
$token = 'xioxnuuebn7tlh8ytu7781t14w7ftwmp';

$opts = array('http' => array('method' => "GET", 'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\nConnection: close\r\n")); 
$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
stream_context_set_option($context, "http", "protocol_version", 1.1); 
fpassthru(fopen($wsdlUrl, 'r', false, $context)); 
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token));
$serviceArgs = array("id"=>1);

try{
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array('version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context));
    $soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerAccountServiceV1($serviceArgs);
}catch(Exception $e){
    $e->getMessage();
}
    var_dump($soapResponse);exit;
```

Can anyone share the code to make SOAP connection in Magento2.x

In Magento1.x the below code works fine to connect SOAP

```
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/magento_28_03/index.php/api/soap?wsdl';
$apiUser = 'testUser'; 
$apiKey = 'admin123';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
try{
    $client = new SoapClient($apiUrl, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
} catch (SoapFault  $e) {
    echo 'Error in Soap Connection : '.$e->getMessage();
}
try {
    $session = $client->login($apiUser, $apiKey);
    if($session) echo 'SOAP Connection Successful.';
    else echo 'SOAP Connection Failed.';

} catch (SoapFault  $e) {
    echo 'Wrong Soap credentials : '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

But the above doesn't work for Magento 1. Can anyone say, what changes the above code needs to work fine for Magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SOAP API call follow the below

test.php

```
<?php
$token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');



$addArgs = array('num1'=>2, 'num2'=>1);// Get Request
$sumArgs = array('nums'=>array(2,1000));// Post request


//$wsdlUrl = YOUR_BASE_URL."soap?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1,customerCustomerRepositoryV1,alanKentCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1";//To declar multiple
$wsdlUrl = YOUR_BASE_URL."soap?wsdl&services=alanKentCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1";
try{
    $opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    
    $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
    $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
    $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error1 : '.$e->getMessage();
}

try{
    $soapResponse = $soapClient->alanKentCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1Add($addArgs);print_r($soapResponse);
    $soapResponse = $soapClient->alanKentCalculatorWebServiceCalculatorV1Sum($sumArgs);print_r($soapResponse);          
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error2 : '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

`http://YOUR_BASE_URL/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from  : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tells you all you need to know; the URL you're trying to load isn't a proper WSDL.

What are the contents of: http://localhost/magento20_0407/soap/default?wsdl_list=1

Comment: Its an xml response, the same we get by running the apiUrl in case of Magento1.x

Comment: According to the error you get, it's not an XML that starts with <

All WSDL's start with the following:

    <?xml version="1.0"

Comment: I checked the view source of that xml. Everything is properly defined.  And moreover that format is coming from Magento right?

Comment: Is there a whitespace at the start of the file or <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>__HERE__<definitions...... ?

Comment: I copied the view source code and pasted in a text file. Checked it thoroughly. There is no space at all. It's a new line only. BUT NO SPACE.